# How to customize the Meteor accounts verification email template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

How to customize meteor account email templates? In Meteor startup I have:

```
Accounts.config({
  sendVerificationEmail: true
});
```

Is there a way to configure email template? For example, there is a verification link in email, I have to change the link into button.

Comment: Check the sample in the [auth docs](http://auth-docs.meteor.com/#accounts_emailtemplates).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can customise the `verifyEmail` component by using the following function:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.text = function(user, url) {
    return 'Your custom text, URL:' + url;
};
```

Since you want to change the link, you may want to use:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html = function(user, url) {
    /* Return your HTML code here: */
    return '<h1>Thank you for your registration.</h1><br/><a href="' + url + '">Verify eMail</a>';
};
```

Read more about **[`Accounts.emailTemplates`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_emailtemplates)**.

Comment: You are my saviors. And thanks a lot for your time to compose answers for me. I hope you remember me on twitter :)

Comment: Hey, works, but in the email  I see the tags html "h1" and "br" ... Is like the email google ingore the html.
Thanks

Comment: @TigerSpirt Hi, I submitted an answer to your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41493811/5107545), but since I am on my iPhone, code formatting may not be perfect. I will fix this as soon as I get back home.

Answer (score 1):

Just to bring more light on this.

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail = {
    subject() {
        return "Activate your account now!";
    },
    text(user, url) {
        return 'Hey ' + user.profile.name 
        + '! Verify your e-mail by following the link below:\n\n'
        + url;
    }
 };
```

based on an example from the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-emailTemplates).