# Why is the customized Meteor accounts verification email not display as HTML?

Tags: javascript, meteor, sendmail, meteor-accounts, email-verification

Here's my code in **`imports/api/friends/methods.js`**:

```
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import {Accounts} from "meteor/accounts-base";

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = "....";
    Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "example01  <example01@gmail.com>";
    Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.from  = function () {
        return "example01  <example01@gmail.com>";
    };
    Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.text = function(user, url) {
        return '<h1>Thank you for your registration.</h1><br/><a href="' + url + '">Verify eMail</a>';
    };

}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Customized Meteor accounts verification email does not display HTML]

As you can see, the format is ingnored by Gmail. We can se the HTML tags `<h1>` and `<br>`.

Why are they not display as HTML?

Answer (score 3):

You used the wrong function. If you use `Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.text`, the body will be returned as text and not as HTML. So instead, you should use `Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html`.

For example:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html = function(user, url) {
    /* Return your HTML code here: */
    return '<h1>Thank you for your registration.</h1><br/><a href="' + url + '">Verify eMail</a>';
};
```

Read more about **[`Accounts.emailTemplates`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_emailtemplates)**.